# error sending email vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 67.69.240.69:25

```
    Dim smtpClient As New SmtpClient()
    Dim message As New MailMessage()
    Dim fromAddress As New MailAddress("news@ffff.ca")
    smtpClient.Host = "smtp10.bellnet.ca"
    smtpClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("news", "1235!")

    smtpClient.Port = "25"
    message.From = fromAddress
    message.To.Add("khs@ddddd.com")
    message.Subject = "eyjeyjey afsdf"

    message.Body = "Hello from aaaaa"
    message.IsBodyHtml = True
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = True
    smtpClient.Send(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bell Canada blocks the default SMTP port of 25.

See [this link](https://support.freecrm.com/support/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=160) for a partial list.